# Missing headers on android webview using express lan server

Tags: android, express, webview, http-headers, godot

I'm making a sort of home console, that serves web games on lan to multiple devices, it already works with web and unity web exports, but with godot 4 I'm having problems. Godot has some problems as you can see here
[image]

Adding this to the expess server fixes the issue on the desktop+electron+iframe app:

```
res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');
res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
```

but on android + web-view + iframe app I'm still having the same error, it seems the headers are not being sent. I'm using self signed certificate so that may have something to do with this problem but is not very clear, it may be something else..

this is my android web view code:

```
   import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.net.http.SslError
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler
import android.webkit.WebResourceError
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient

class WebViewHandler(private val context: Context, private val webView: WebView) {

    init {
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webSettings.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = false

        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false)
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false)

        val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("-prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val ipAddress = sharedPreferences.getString("ipAddress", "")

        val ipPageUrl = "..."
        var url = ""
        if (ipAddress != null && ipAddress != "") {
            url = "..."
        } else {
            webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
            webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
            url = ipPageUrl
        }

        webView.loadUrl(url)

        webView.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

        val timeoutHandler = Handler()
        val timeoutRunnable = Runnable {
            Log.d("WebView", "Timer expired. Loading static IP page.")
            webView.loadUrl(ipPageUrl)
        }
        timeoutHandler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, 3000)

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                Log.d("WebView", "Page finished loading: $url")
                timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(timeoutRunnable)  // Invalidate the timer when the page finishes loading
            }

            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                Log.d("WebView", "Received error: $error")
                webView.loadUrl(ipPageUrl)
            }

            override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
                handler?.proceed() 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you've tried/read: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl and https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config along with how you are testing (emulator/device, OS version).